# How can I change my output Vertical to Horizontal

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

## I want to make my output like this

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

What change need for this program. Make my output in Vertical to Horizontal

### Program

```
 i = 1
    while i<=10 :
      print(i)
      i= i+1
```

### Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

# I want to make my output like this 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this:

```py
i = 1
while i<=10 :
    print(i, end=' ')
    i= i+1
print()
```

Output:

```py
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```